# Spring MVC Ajax Search Form Thymeleaf

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, spring-data, thymeleaf

So I'm trying to create a search form in the navbar of my site, and I'm using ajax to submit the form.  I have other working search forms in my web app so I know how to do that.  And I have the ajax submitting properly.  I just don't know how to get the data from the form and use it in the controller to get the result that I want.

The way I'm doing the search function is by creating a searchForm.java object that has a string variable called searchString and I populate that and then query it against the database in the controller using spring data methods in my repository class.

So here's what my jquery ajax form looks like, and in the console on the chrome developer tools it returns "setSearch" like I tell it to in the controller, and I know that's an issue, I just don't really know how to fix it.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchButton").on("click", function(ev) {
        $.ajax({
            url : "/setSearch/search",
            type : "post",
            data : {
                "newSearch" : $("#newSearch").val()
            },
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error : function() {
                console.log("There was an error");
            }

        });
    });
  });
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Here's my thymeleaf html page

```
<form action = "setSearch" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="newSearch"></input>
            <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="searchButton">Search</button>
</form>
```

This is my searchForm.java object

```
public class SearchForm {

private String searchString;

public String getSearchString()
{
    return searchString;
}

public void setSearchString(String searchString)
{
    this.searchString = searchString;
}
}
```

Here's my controller, and I know this won't work, because I'm returning a string and not a json object(I think that's right).  But I tried to change it and I get a lot of errors, and I'm not sure how I should go about this.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/setSearch/search", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String search (@RequestParam String newSearch, ModelMap model)
{   
    List<QuestionAnswerSet> questionAnswerSetByQuestion = (List<QuestionAnswerSet>) questionAnswerSetRepo.findByQuestionContaining(newSearch);
    model.put("searchResult", questionAnswerSetByQuestion);

    return "setSearch";
}
```

Here's a working example of a non ajax search function in my controller, so you guys can see what I'm trying to do.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/setSearch", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String searchGet(ModelMap model) {

    SearchForm searchForm = new SearchForm();
    model.put("searchForm", searchForm);

    return "setSearch";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/setSearch", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String searchPost(@ModelAttribute SearchForm searchForm, ModelMap model) {

    List<QuestionAnswerSet> questionAnswerSetByQuestion = (List<QuestionAnswerSet>) questionAnswerSetRepo.findByQuestionContaining(searchForm.getSearchString());
    model.put("searchResult", questionAnswerSetByQuestion);

    return "setSearch";
}
```

Let me know if I left anything out or if you would need to see any more code to see my issue.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only submitting one parameter and it will be restfull there is no need for form or POST

Here is a simple example of how I would do a search that returns a array of objects from database. I hope you can use it to implement what you need.

HTML

```
<form>
<label for="search_input">Search:</label>
<input type="text" id="search_input">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
$.get("/search", {term: $('#search_input').val()}, function(data) {
// do your data manipulation and transformation here
});
</script>
```

Controller

```
RequestMapping("/search")
public @ResponseBody List searchPost(@RequestParameter("term") String query) {

    List<Object> retVal = getListOfObjectFromDbBasedOnQuery(query);

    return retVal;
}
```

Lot simpler (from a logical perspective), remember in RESTfull terms post is used to create objects. Retrieving data use GET only.

Comment: That does look a lot simpler, I'm a beginner in the javascript department, so what kind of "data manipulation and transformation" would that require, also is it possible to redirect to the search page with the data submitted?

Comment: "data manipulation and transformation" is to indicate you do whatever you want with the returned data within that space. i.e. display it, transform it, whatever you wish. And yes it is possible to redirect to another page with data submitted but that is a whole new question, and really you shouldn't be doing that unless you have wizard like flows where your sign up in in steps. If you only going to be doing search then you should make sure data is present before submitting on client end via "required" attribute in HTML5

Comment: Ok, I know this may be a separate question, but how does a  typical navbar search work then?

Comment: There is no one size fits all answer there. It really is a case of what do you need your search to do. A navbar based search indicates a quick search or a search based on a single parameter. Advanced search where its a massive form is where you input multiple parameters for usage in your search. Example google.com is single parameter, google.com.au/advanced_search is a complex form one.

Comment: @dochsner can you accept the answer if it helped, appreciate the support

Comment: this helped me to realize I was making a beginner mistake by using a form when it wasn't necessary.